# Is Fock state a squeezed state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, squeezed-states

Is Fock state a squeezed state?
I assume that 'yes', that is how it beats shot-noise limit
the next question is
that what is its  complementary variable?
Basically is delta N -> delta p
what is its delta x?

Answer (score 1):

Put more effort into your question and I'd give a higher-effort answer.

But in short:
You are correct that things which less shotnoise than the vaccum are in some sense "squeezed" (although there's also a specific definition of a "squeezed state" even though other states that are not these squeezed states can also look "squeezed").

But what matters is if the variance of the E-field is less than the vaccum. Fock-states look like solutions to the harmonic oscillator. If you look at them, they get more stretched than the origional vaccum state, and are therefore not squeezed.

To get squeezing you need to consider superpostions of them so that they cancel and give you a shape that is smaller than the vacuum state. And generally superpositions of even fock states can cancel out in a way to do this.